Injecting dll to x86 process above user-virtual-address
First, sorry for my bad english.
I have some program that heavely virtualized and doing dll injection behavior.
The target process is x86 process and execute in wow64 system.
When I saw the target process's dump after dll has been injected, the dll is allocated after 0x7fffffff address. (PE Header seems deleted)

So, I used APIMonitor tool and hook several suspicious API, the program just call VirtualAlloc API and address beyond 0x7fffffff was given by it's parameter.

I heard the address after 0x7fffffff in x86 process is used by kernel. So, I think just using VirtualAlloc API to allocate after 0x7fffffff will not be succeed, even if program execute on wow64 system.
And, I just make program that using VirtualAlloc API with higher address and test it, the allocation failed with ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS(0x1E7)
Is there any way that allocate address after 0x7fffffff in x86 process using VirtualAlloc API?
I hope for your guide. thank you.

try to set the dll loading address to the process
by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-property-pages?view=msvc-170#base-address
this works in some cases - I've tested it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/base-base-address?view=msvc-170
